# iPhone HelloWorld Game crashes in Cocos2d

Tags: iphone, objective-c, cocos2d-iphone

I just created a HelloWorld app using cocos2d framework. Installation went smooth but when I created a Helloworld project and ran it the app crashes. It loads for a second and then quits.

I am using XCode 4 and iPhone Simulator 4.3. I am not able to find a file HelloWorldScene.m. Its not coming for me.

Comment: There has to be some form of error message from the crash. What does the log say?

Comment: Program ended with exit code: 1

Comment: http://www.cocos2d-iphone.org/forum/topic/15476

Comment: all it took was to google that error code. you should try that sometime.

Answer (score 0):

Please provide more information: Is there any useful information in the console output? What is in your HelloWorldScene.m? Where does the app crash when you run it with debugging symbols on (ie. "Breakpoints" on)?

Comment: You are using a Sandy Bridge MBP, and there is a bug in the simulator (from Apple, not cocos2d) that prevents you from using iOS 4.3. You need to switch the target down to 4.2 or lower. You can do that by clicking your project (the top entry in the project navigator), under targets your project should be selected, and under the summary tab there is a dropdown menu for Deployment Target. Set this on 4.2 or lower, then on the top left of the Xcode window set Scheme to 4.2 lower (iPhone or iPad does not matter).